# Translation of C# ActionCommand:ICommand into VB.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, translation, icommand

I found a C# class ActionCommand, that implements ICommand and bases on delegates for Execute and CanExecute. Looks perfect for me so far.

```
  public class ActionCommand : ICommand
  {
    private readonly Action<object> _executeHandler;
    private readonly Func<object, bool> _canExecuteHandler;

    public ActionCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute)
    {
      if (execute == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Execute cannot be null");
      _executeHandler = execute;
      _canExecuteHandler = canExecute;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
      add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
      remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
      _executeHandler(parameter);
    }
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
      if (_canExecuteHandler == null)
        return true;
      return _canExecuteHandler(parameter);
    }
  }
```

Now I translated it into my needed VB.net variant (using code translators and some hands on)

```
Public Class ActionCommand
  Implements ICommand

  Public Event CanExecuteChanged As EventHandler Implements ICommand.CanExecuteChanged

  Private ReadOnly _executeHandler As Action(Of Object)
  Private ReadOnly _canExecuteHandler As Func(Of Object, Boolean)

  Public Sub New(ByVal execute As Action(Of Object),
                 ByVal canExecute As Func(Of Object, Boolean))
    If execute Is Nothing Then
      Throw New ArgumentNullException("Execute cannot be null")
    End If
    _executeHandler = execute
    _canExecuteHandler = canExecute
  End Sub

  Public Sub Execute(ByVal parameter As Object) Implements ICommand.Execute
    _executeHandler(parameter)
  End Sub

  Public Function CanExecute(ByVal parameter As Object) As Boolean Implements ICommand.CanExecute
    If (_canExecuteHandler Is Nothing) Then
      Return True
    End If
    Return _canExecuteHandler(parameter)
  End Function
End Class
```

My problem is around CanExecuteChanged and registering/mapping the events from CommandManager.RequerySuggested to CanExecuteChanged. The online code translator suggest the following:

```
Public Custom Event CanExecuteChanged As EventHandler
    AddHandler(ByVal value As EventHandler)
        CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value
    End AddHandler
    RemoveHandler(ByVal value As EventHandler)
        CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value
    End RemoveHandler
End Event
```

but this cannot satify ICommand.CanExecuteChanged
Can someone please help how to translate or solve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This article from [MALIGUI .NET BLOG](http://windowsclient.net/blogs/maligui/archive/2010/01/22/input-bindings-in-mvvm-wpf-design-vb-net.aspx) might help:

```
Public Custom Event CanExecuteChanged As EventHandler _
    Implements ICommand.CanExecuteChanged
        AddHandler(ByVal value As EventHandler)
            Dim handler2 As EventHandler
            Dim canExecuteCommand = __CanExecuteCommand
            Do
                handler2 = canExecuteCommand
                Dim handler3 = DirectCast(System.Delegate.Combine(handler2, value), EventHandler)
                canExecuteCommand = Interlocked.CompareExchange((__CanExecuteCommand), handler3, handler2)
            Loop While (Not canExecuteCommand Is handler2)
            __CanExecuteCommand = canExecuteCommand
        End AddHandler
        RemoveHandler(ByVal value As EventHandler)
            Dim handler2 As EventHandler
            Dim canExecuteCommand = __CanExecuteCommand
            Do
                handler2 = canExecuteCommand
                Dim handler3 = DirectCast(System.Delegate.Remove(handler2, value), EventHandler)
                canExecuteCommand = Interlocked.CompareExchange((__CanExecuteCommand), handler3, handler2)
            Loop While (Not canExecuteCommand Is handler2)
            __CanExecuteCommand = canExecuteCommand
        End RemoveHandler
        RaiseEvent(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
            If (__CanExecuteCommand IsNot Nothing) Then
                __CanExecuteCommand.Invoke(sender, e)
            End If
        End RaiseEvent
    End Event
```

Comment: The part around RaiseEvent was the key to success. With this, the custom event can implement IComamnd.CanExecuteChanged. I simplified it in that way, that it looks somewhat more like the answer from MarkJ.

Answer (score 9):

```
Public Custom Event CanExecuteChanged As EventHandler
    AddHandler(ByVal value As EventHandler)
        AddHandler CommandManager.RequerySuggested, value
    End AddHandler
    RemoveHandler(ByVal value As EventHandler)
        RemoveHandler CommandManager.RequerySuggested, value
    End RemoveHandler
End Event
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, and in addition with the RaiseEvent-Part from HadleyHope the Custom Event matches the interface ICommand

Answer (score 9):

I think what you are looking for is more like:

```
    Public Custom Event CanExecuteChanged As EventHandler _
                   Implements ICommand.CanExecuteChanged
        AddHandler(ByVal value As EventHandler)
            AddHandler CommandManager.RequerySuggested, value
        End AddHandler

        RemoveHandler(ByVal value As EventHandler)
            RemoveHandler CommandManager.RequerySuggested, value
        End RemoveHandler

        RaiseEvent(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
            CanExecute(sender)
        End RaiseEvent
    End Event
```

Comment: I've been looking for this for a while ... Thank you :)